# Data model for User Notifications of many Types

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-modeling

I am trying to figure out how to model notifications. This is what I tried.

```
public class NotificationType
{
    public int NotificationTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}

public class Notification
{
    public int NotificationID { get; set; }
    public bool ReadStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NotificationType")]
    public int NotificationTypeID { get; set; }

    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Frankly, I feel like I have no idea what I am doing still, but let me tell you what I was trying to do, if it's a bad idea, tell me, if not please tell me how I do it.

I have `Notifications` that are for actions that occur related to a `Comment`, `Reply` and `Project` - That's why I have all those navigation properties and fields. I want to basically use the `NotificationType` to determine what it is and then use the appropriate ID field to get the information to display the notification to a user.

First problem, I can't seem to make those ID (`CommentID` `ProjectID` ) fields Nullable so I don't always have to have them.

How to I make them nullable using data annotations and or the fluent api OR design my model better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them nullable properties

```
public class Notification
{
    public int NotificationID { get; set; }
    public bool ReadStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NotificationType")]
    public int NotificationTypeID { get; set; }

    public int? CommentID { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectID { get; set; }

    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>().HasOptional(n => n.Comment).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.CommentID);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this a kind of complex but complete notification system : http://library.blackboard.com/ref/df5b20ed-ce8d-4428-a595-a0091b23dda3/Content/Mini_TOCs/mt_admin_app_system_manage_comm_notify_frame.htm
I think that many good ideas can be borrowed from it.